# How do I left align the text and align these equal signs?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

How do I left align the text and align these equal signs? As for the equal sign I used `\,` and it kind of works but I want to be more close. Is there a smaller spacing than this or any way to better align these equal signs?

[image]

The expected output is something like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

Input data \,\, =  2000\\
Deleted data \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,= 500\\
Remaining data = 2000 - 500 =1500   


\end{document}
```

Sorry that I probably should have mentioned that I'm going to put the text inside a table like this.
The solution @Mico gave works but not in this table. So I think the table change the formating somehow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\label{tab: this is a table} 
\begin{tabular}{cc} \\ \toprule
\textbf{No}      & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
1         & 9                         \\
2         & 5                      \\
3         & 3                      \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ L @{{}={}} l }
\text{Input data}     &  2000 \\
\text{Deleted data}   &  500  \\
\text{Remaining data}  &  2000-500=1500
\end{array}
\]
\end{tabular}} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What prevents you from using a `tabular`?

Comment: @JasperHabicht actually I'm going to put this in a cell of a table.

Comment: Now that you edited your question: You already nest `tabular`s, so why not just use a `tabular` with two columns that is placed in the cell? Aligning things will be very easy then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a different `array`-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ L @{{}={}} l }
Input data     &  2000 \\
Deleted data   &  500  \\
Remaning data  &  2000-500=1500
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's how I would modify the OP's addtional example code to embed the `array` inside a two-column `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{This is a table\strut}
\label{tab:this is a table} 
\begin{tabular}{@{} cc @{}} 
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \textbf{Example} \\ 
\midrule
1  & 9  \\
2  & 5  \\
3  & 3  \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{%
   \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}$
   \begin{array}{ L @{{}={}} l }
   Input data     &  2000 \\
   Deleted data   &  500  \\
   Remaining data &  2000-500=1500
   \end{array}$
} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you check the my updated post? Your solution does work well alone but it's my fault that I didn't mention it clearly that I'm going to put it in a table.

Comment: @hana - If you (a) change from display math to inline math, i.e., if you replace `\[` and `\]` with `$`, and (b) place `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}` before the initial `$` symbol, this method works fine inside a cell of a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @hana - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thanks, it works with table now.

Comment: The "accept" vote on this answer, placed a short while ago, raised my total rep count on TeX.SE to exactly 444,000 points. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Rarely used but not to be forgotten: the `tabbing` environment. Inside a tabular, you would need to wrap it in a `\parbox` or similar, however.

(I placed the numbers in math mode for nicer typsetting.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
Remaining data \= \kill      % needed to define the position of the tab
Input data     \>$= 2000$ \\
Deleted data   \>$= 500$  \\
Remaining data \>$= 2000 - 500 = 1500$ 
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

Given the fact that you want to place this inside a table cell that aready has a nested `tabular` inside, why not just do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\label{tab: this is a table} 
\begin{tabular}{cc} \\ \toprule
\textbf{No}  & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
1            & 9                 \\
2            & 5                 \\
3            & 3                 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
    Input data      & $2000$ \\
    Deleted data    & $500$  \\
    Remaining data  & $2000-500=1500$
    \end{tabular}
}                                \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use the `p{}` column type if you want to specifiy the with of a certain column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\label{tab: this is a table} 
\begin{tabular}{cc} \\ \toprule
\textbf{No}  & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
1            & 9                 \\
2            & 5                 \\
3            & 3                 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}l@{}}
    Input data      & $2000$ \\
    Deleted data    & $500$  \\
    Remaining data  & $2000-500=1500$
    \end{tabular}
}                                \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion looks good too.

Comment: If I want to  add more space between the text and the number in the last 3 lines, how would you do it? I tried add `\text{       }` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @hana Consecutive spaces will be reduced (except for verbatim environments). If you want to enlarge the left column, better change its type from `l` to `p{4cm}` or something similar.

Comment: I think you misundertood my question. In this table your code looks very nice. However, in some table where the second columns data become long so I want to add more space between for example `input  data` and `2000` so to push the 2000 further away to make it look nicer.

Comment: @hana See my edit. But maybe this is not what you want. But then, maybe one of the other answers is better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

This uses a tabular and `@{$\null =\null$}` to add correctly spaced equal signs between the column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\label{tab: this is a table} 
\begin{tabular}{cc} \\ \toprule
\textbf{No}      & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
1         & 9                         \\
2         & 5                      \\
3         & 3                      \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{$\null =\null$}l}
Input data     &  2000 \\
Deleted data   &  500  \\
Remaining data  &  $2000-500=1500$
\end{tabular}} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. The LaTeX kernel defines`\null` as `\hbox{}`. Could you comment on the difference between your solution for the inter-column element, `@{\hbox{}=\hbox{}}`, and the one I used in my answer, *viz*., `@{{}={}}`?

Comment: @Mico - Mostly I didn't really notice the similarity.  I regard `{}` more as `\begingroup\endgroup`.  Adding `\null` around math operators is fairly common practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `array` environment, which only works in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
    \text{Input data} &=  2000 \\
    \text{Deleted data} &= 500 \\
    \text{Remaining data} &= 2000 - 500 = 1500
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, it works.

Comment: With this solution, the amount of whitespace around the `=` symbols is quite asymmetric. It is most easily visible in the third row.

Comment: you need `l@{}l` here